# Is there a way to deserialize raw byte[] back into thrift object without knowing its thrift type?

Tags: cross-platform, message-queue, protocol-buffers, thrift, cross-language

I'm running a project that requires

- inter-communication between different programming languages (mostly java, c++).
- could serialize/deserialize into both binary format and json format.
- IDL to generate class code for different languages

Thrift matches these criteria perfectly, although we don't need its RPC functions. We will be sending/receiving the serialized thrift data via MQ. Serializing the object is very straight forward. However, when it comes to deserializing, we cannot do something like this:

```
byte[] data = recv();
Object object = TDeserializer.deserialize(data);
if (object instanceof TypeA) {
    TypeA a = (TypeA) object;
} else if (object instanceof TypeB) {
    TypeB b = (TypeB) object;
}
```

It seems we have to tell thrift exactly which struct it needs to deserialize into like:

```
byte[] data = recv();
TypeA a;
TDeserializer.deserialize(a, data);
```

Just wondering if there's a way to deserialize raw data into thrift object without knowing its exact type.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thrift serialized message itself doesn't contain type info, so deserializer must be aware of message data type. However, it's possible to wrap all necessary data types into union.

Thrift code:

```
union Message {
    1: TypeA a;
    2: TypeB b;
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
byte[] data = recv();
Message msg;
TDeserializer.deserialize(msg, data);
<find out message type with msg.getSetField()>
```

If you need to add new message types, just add another field into union. If you don't touch old field IDs, you will retain backward compatibility:

```
union Message {
    1: TypeA a;
    2: TypeB b;
    3: TypeC c; <-- OK
}
```

You will be able to receive messages from old producers (they will never send `TypeC` messages) and send `TypeA`/`TypeB` messages to old consumers. If you send `TypeC` message to the consumer that's not aware of field #3, it will get exception.

The big advantage of this approach is that type information is very compact. If you use `TCompactProtocol`, type info will only take 1 extra byte in most cases (if the field IDs in `Message` are less that 127).

Be careful, if you change field IDs, you will loose backward compatibility. For example:

```
union Message {
    1: TypeA a;
    2: TypeC c; <-- Wrong
    3: TypeB b; <-- Wrong
    4: TypeD d; <-- OK
}
```

Comment: That is very comprehensive answer. Thanks for this! This will fix my concerns. Strange that union is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Does this method works for Golang? I'm using the official implementation and cannot find this magical method on an union struct. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for